# ReferenceError: FirebaseFirestore is not defined firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a firebase function that triggers when object metadata on a cloud storage bucket changes, but when the function triggers I am getting an error:

```
ReferenceError: FirebaseFirestore is not defined
at addKapsulFromStorageObject
```

Here's the code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

import admin = require('firebase-admin');
import { ObjectMetadata } from "firebase-functions/lib/providers/storage";
admin.initializeApp();

const database = admin.firestore();
database.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })

const KAPSUL_COLLECTION_ID = 'kapsuls';

exports.onKapsulFileAdded = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) =>{
    addKapsulFromStorageObject(object);
})

exports.onKapsulMetaDataUpdated = functions.storage.object().onMetadataUpdate(async (object) => {
    addKapsulFromStorageObject(object);
});

async function addKapsulFromStorageObject(object: ObjectMetadata) {
    const metaData = object.metadata;
    if(metaData == null || metaData == undefined) return;

    const kapsulId = uuidv4()
    console.log("Adding Kapsul to firestore.")
    await database.collection(KAPSUL_COLLECTION_ID).doc(kapsulId).set({
        id: kapsulId,
        coordinates: new FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint(parseFloat( metaData['lat']), parseFloat(metaData['long'])),
        first_name: metaData['first_name'],
        last_name:  metaData['last_name'],
        date: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(metaData['date'])),
        is_online: JSON.parse(metaData['is_online']),
        is_paid: JSON.parse(metaData['is_paid']),
        always_unlockable: metaData['always_unlockable'],
        title: metaData['title'],
        unlock_distance: parseFloat(metaData['unlock_distance']),
        video_url: object.mediaLink,
        metaData: metaData['thumbnail_url']
    });
}
```

I'm not really sure what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirebaseFirestore` is not defined but you are using it at 2 places:

```
date: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(metaData['date'])),
// and
coordinates: new FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint(parseFloat( metaData['lat']), parseFloat(metaData['long'])),
```

Try using `admin.firestore` instead:

```
coordinates: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(parseFloat( metaData['lat']), parseFloat(metaData['long'])),
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

date: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(metaData['date'])),
```

If you were following any tutorial, then they may have declared that somewhere above like:

```
const FirebaseFirestore = admin.firestore
```

Comment: Trying this now.

Comment: This was the fix! Thank you so much.